# Streaming video from shared Mac folder to AppleTV?

Tags: macos, iphone, mac, appletv, airplay

I just bought a new AppleTV and will be getting it soon, and I want to know how I can stream my movies which are located on a shared drive to it?

Right now, my videos are in a folder which is shared by my MBP (which is running SL) and have various formats. I've been trying to find a way to show these on my ATV without having to convert them.

I've heard about AirFlick, but I'm running Lion and apparently it doesn't work (someone tell me I'm wrong). I also vaguely remember a way to stream it to my iPhone4, and then stream that to AirPlay on the ATV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AirFlick with Lion as long as you use it in tandem with AirVideo. Check out this blog post for instructions. It worked for me.

http://johncaruso.ca/index.php?post=360

Answer (score 1):

You are right about streaming to the iPhone (or iPad) and then to the ATV. Check out the [VLC streamer](http://download.hobbyistsoftware.com/Download/desktop?file=VLCStreamer/VLCStreamer.dmg). The application is installed on iOS, and a companion app goes on the computer. VLC Streamer will transcode non-native video (e.g., AVI) from the computer, pipe it to the iOS device, and then pipe *that* to the ATV via AirPlay. I have tested this and it works exactly as described. The quality of your results will be dependent, of course, on your LAN bandwidth and processing speed of the machines. You can set some of these parameters in VLC Streamer, though, which maximizes output. Enjoy!

Comment: I though it was VLC. I assume then that the file that VLC is sending could reside on a network folder, and then sends it to the iPhone and to the ATV. Luckily, our wifi connection is pretty damn fast ;D

Comment: Yes, it can definitely be on a networked directory. I have exactly that setup running.

Comment: Do I need to send it to the iPhone, then the ATV? Or can I stream straight from the Mac to the ATV?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. You also have to install the helper app on your computer. Check out the VLC Streamer page [here](http://hobbyistsoftware.com/VLCStreamer) for more info

Comment: The problem with this is that it puts a local copy of the media on my computer, taking up space. You mentioned you were able to have it play movies from a network drive, how so?

Comment: Put the Streamer assistant on the computer/server hooked to your network. Manually add the path to the drive from the VLC Streamer app on your iPad/iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

If they're MPEG-4 formatted videos, just add them to iTunes.  ATV will play anything in your iTunes (must be MP4 though, not AVI even if iTunes would play it).

If you want non-MP4 video, you'll need to jailbreak your ATV & install Plex.

Comment: I am planning on jailbrekaing anyways, but I don't want to have to put them into iTunes, but run them off the shared folder...